# How to determine whether a validation study produces acceptable results?

Tags: mechanical-engineering

I have a method developed to predict results of a signal that outputs an root mean squared error (RMSE) for each subject. Combining all 40 subjects, I get a mean RMSE of 5.5 with a standard deviation of 2.8. This is comparable to previous literature.

Now I did a validation study using 5 subjects and obtained a mean RMSE of 12.4 with a standard deviation of 4.4.

To me these seem drastically different and I would not be able to conclude that the validation is good, but I want a more quantitative way to describe that. How would I go about this?

Comment: Better on Cross Validated stack, but 5 subjects compared to 40? You need more...

Comment: Did you use the same calculation for variance, in both calculations? The population (40 subjects) and the sample (5 subjects) or did you use N and N-1 respectively? or are you treating both as a population just with wildly varying quantities?